# Add querySelectorAll to add a class to a button

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector

I'm having difficulty with using Javascript to add a class to a button.

Context: I have multiple cards in an instragram type format with a post and a "like" button. I want to add a class of **card__like-button** which changes the image to a filled heart but i remembered that querySelector only applies to the first element, instead i tried using querySelectorAll but now the code doesn't apply to anything.

First attemp:

```
// Controls for active like button
let likeButton = document.querySelector(".card__like-button");
   
// Event listener for like button click
likeButton.addEventListener("click", likeButtonClick);
    
// Add class on button click
function likeButtonClick() {
likeButton.classList.toggle("card__like-button_active");
    }
```

**Second attemp**

```
// Controls for active like button
let likeButton = document.querySelectorAll(".card__like-button");

// Event listener for like button click
likeButton.addEventListener("click", likeButtonClick);

// Add class on button click
function likeButtonClick() {
  likeButton.classList.toggle("card__like-button_active");
}
```

I created the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/aegisnull/pen/mdXpwJo) to replicate the problem.

I've search on the site, w3schools documentation, etc. and can't seem to find what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```js
let likeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".card__like-button");
Array.from(likeButtons).forEach(ele => {
    ele.addEventListener("click", likeButtonClick);
});
// Add class on button click
function likeButtonClick() {
  this.classList.toggle("card__like-button_active");
}
```

Comment: Instead of "Try it" you should add some notes to your answer explaining what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the document.querySelectorAll method will return an array of NodeList [details see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), you cannot directly assign the addEventListener event to a list.

Instead, you have to loop through each element and assign events to it

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card__like-button").forEach(ele => {
    ele.addEventListener("click", likeButtonClick);
});

// Add class on button click
function likeButtonClick() {
  this.classList.toggle("card__like-button_active");
}
```